# Get Attribute model by attribute_code in Magento

Tags: magento

How could I get `Attribute model` (from: **`eav_attribute`** table) by `attribute_code` in Magento?
Notice:
- I don't care what is entity_type.
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You have to know `entity_type` because you can have the same `attribute_code` for different entities. So to get attribute model:

```
$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode($entity_type, $attributeCode);
```

`$entity_type` parameter can be `numeric` (id directly), `string` (for example `'catalog_product'` or `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY`) or it can be instance of model `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type`

Comment: Thanks. I will try and confirm the result to you.

Comment: I used your code above to find out if short_description is 'Visible on Product View Page on Front-end':

$attributeShortDescription = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'short_description');
$attributeShortDescription->getIsVisibleOnFront();

Comment: version using constants: 
$_attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attributeCode);

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can read the attributes by filter the collection

```
   Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', array('in' => $codes) )
```

Since I need the attributes from the Product by code, I do it like this:

```
    $codes = (array) $codes; 
    $res = array_intersect_key($this->getAttributes(), array_flip($codes));
```

$codes is an attribute_code-array
Scope: extended Mage_Catalog_Model_Product

Answer (score 3):

```
$attribute_code = "flat_printing_quantity"; 
$attribute_details =
Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, $attribute_code);
$attribute = $attribute_details->getData();
echo $attribute['attribute_id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

$attributeModel = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode(1, 'is_approved');
echo $attributeModel->getAttributeId();

Comment: Not only does this have data which is specific to only one of many scenarios, but it also echoes the accepted answer, the code is not formatted and there is no explanation.